# Filtering a python list, while coupling non-filtered terms to other lists.

Tags: python, list, filter, lambda

I am trying to filter out items in a list containing the term "FX" using the filter function and a lambda. This works fine:

```
MarketnoFX=list(filter(lambda x: "FX" not in x, Openmarket))
```

However, this list needs to be coupled to two other lists containing numerical value, so say if the xth term is omitted from this list (via the creation of a new list), it must also be omitted from the other 2 lists. I would usually simply use list comprehensions.

```
Openmarket=[someitems]
coupled1=[]
coupled2=[]

    for item in Openmarket:
        if "FX" in item:
            pass
        else:
            someotherlist.append(item)
            k=Openmarket.index(entry)
            someotherotherlist.append(coupled1[k])
```

However, doing this doesn't produce the correct results, and upon printing the index of items containing "FX", I get for example it showing that it is finding the 12th and 33rd terms twice, and the 71st term only once.

The filter function seems like a more elegant way of doing things, but how do I couple it to the other lists? I have read about a zip function, but I am not sure how to apply it here. I am not a very experienced Python programmer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) is a good way to solve this.

Basically, it can takes three lists and iterate through each n-th element at the same time, so this is very useful here.

As it returns a list of tuples, you can then filter it to keep tuples where the first value (which is the element from `Openmarket`) does not contains `FX`. Elements from `someotherlist` and `someotherotherlist` are filtered at the same time.

Finaly, you can get back your inital lists by "unzipping" the list of tuples, thanks to unpacking.

**Python 2**

```
zipped = zip(Openmarket, someotherlist, someotherotherlist)
filtered = filter(lambda (a, b, c): "FX" not in a, zipped)
Openmarket, someotherlist, someotherotherlist = zip(*filtered)
```

**Python 3**

```
zipped = list(zip(Openmarket, someotherlist, someotherotherlist))
filtered = list(filter(lambda elems: "FX" not in elems[0], zipped))
Openmarket, someotherlist, someotherotherlist = zip(*filtered)
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.5 (I should have stated this in the question), so the first line in your code I think for me would need to be:
    zipped=list((zip(Opendeal, Openresult, Openmarket)))

Comment: @Hanadulset You are absolutely right. This is because `zip()` returns a zip object since Python 3, while it was a simple list before.

Comment: I was actually intended of expanding further but pressing enter posts a comment to my dismay.

I intended on writing:

I am using Python 3.5 (I should have stated this in the question), so the first line in your code I think for me would need to be:

    zipped=list((zip(Opendeal, Openresult, Openmarket)))

So I tried:

    zipped=list((zip(Opendeal, Openresult, Openmarket)))
    zipped=(filter(lambda a,b,c: "FX" not in c, *zipped))

which yields:
TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 200

As an aside, what is the third line of your code for, and what does:
    zip(*zipped) do?

Comment: @Hanadulset I added the code for Python 3, I hope it works as you as expected.